# How to handle null objects in string concatenations in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, nullreferenceexception, string-concatenation

```
Dim response As MyClass = obj.ProcessRequest(strRequest)
Msgbox("This is the response message: " & response.Message)
```

If there is a problem in the *ProcessRequest* method and it returns `null`, then the next line will not work and a `NullReference` exception will be thrown.

What is the easiest way to have `response.Message` evaluate to an empty string if `response` is `null`?

Answer (score 2):

You may use inline [If](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
Msgbox("This is the response message: " & If(response Is Nothing, "", response.Message))
```

but IMO it is more readable to use `if .. else` clause

Answer (score 0):

& Nothing equates to & "".

So the neatest way IMO is:

```
Dim response As MyClass = obj.ProcessRequest(strRequest)
Msgbox("This is the response message: " & response?.Message)
```